# Use of nlme for mixed models of repeated measures with two classifying factors and a covariate

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

Suppose we have a mixed model for repeated measures with response being $y$ and a covariate being $x$(say, age). There are two classification factors $a$ and $b$. Say, 5 psychological patients($a$) in 8 conditions($b$) are measured.

I want to know how I get the estimates of intercepts and slopes (and their standard errors) of the random effects model when:

1. $a$ fixed, $b$ random
2. $b$ fixed, $a$ random
3. Both random

How should the appropriate code look like?

Besides, can you tell me something about the meaning of the following error message?

```
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

Comment: Do you have individual measures for all 8 conditions (crossed factors $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: Yes I have individual measures for all 8 conditions.

Comment: @chl is there any suggestion for me regarding this problem? I have failed to fix it.

Comment: Usually, for the random effects parts, `random=~1|id` corresponds to a random intercept for each statistical unit `id` while `random=~grp|id` would yield random intercept and slopes (for `id` within each level of `grp`). For *crossed random effects*, things are a little bit more complicated and you'll need to use one of the `pdBlocked` together with `pdIdent` (block diagonal VC matrix with diagonal blocks given by multiples of the identity matrix) or `pdSymm` (id. with PD matrices). I would be happy to try to give more details with a small working example.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into the points from your kind suggestion.